# add insert in existing xml file to run update using liquibase

Tags: insert, addition, liquibase, delta

This is regarding Liquibase insert records. Suppose in version v1 I have an xml file with 50 insert records and I want to add 30 more insert records in version 2. Can I go with same file and change id and add these records? Actually, I did in same file and I got a "unique constraints error" while updating commands.

```
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1211)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:600)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value 
violates unique constraint
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the idea is that you would want to have two changesets. You already have a changeset in v1 that adds the first 50. You should add a second changeset to add the next 30. Changesets (for the most part) should be considered immutable once they have been deployed anywhere besides your own local developer database. The main exception to that is changesets that deploy things like functions or procedures, where the SQL code in the file is always the latest and most correct version.